# How Can I install Mac Classic theme in sublime latest version?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am using sublime text editor, and my favorite theme is Mac Classic Theme . But When I updated the editor , con't found the theme. How Can I install Mac Classic Theme In sublime editor ?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

Download the package of "Color Scheme - Legacy" [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/LegacyColorSchemes) -> From the menu: Preferences -> Browse Packages -> Inside the folder that pops up, create a subfolder: **Mac Classic.tmTheme** ->
Drop the **file Mac Classic.tmTheme** in there.

Restart the Sublime and apply the mac classic theme.

Answer (score 5):

You can install the "Color Scheme - Legacy" [package](https://github.com/SublimeText/LegacyColorSchemes) via the "Package Control: Install Package". This should bring the "Color Scheme - Legacy.sublime-package" file into your "Installed Packages" Sublime Text folder. After this you should be able to find the "Mac Classic" scheme in the "Preferences / Color Scheme..." menu.

That being said, due to some unknown error perhaps, but I don't see the "Mac Classic" and other legacy themes after installing the "Color Scheme - Legacy". BUT, if I copy "Mac Classic.tmTheme" from "Color Scheme - Legacy.sublime-package" to any other ".sublime-package" file, they appear!

Here's one way to do this with:

```
cd 'Installed Packages/'
mkdir -p custom-themes
cd custom-themes/
unzip '../Color Scheme - Legacy.sublime-package'
zip ../custom-themes.sublime-package *.tmTheme
cd ..
rm -rf custom-themes/
```

(P.S. The problem of getting Mac Classic to work was also discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SublimeText/comments/71uamg/mac_classic_themecolor_scheme/), on reddit).

Answer (score 2):

Install the "Color Scheme - Legacy" package as described above.
In Windows then go to C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages
You will find Default color scheme package (43Kb) and Legacy package (260Kb). Rename packages so the Legacy package is now named Default. All the previous options inc Mac Classic will now be available.

[screenshot of package names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAEyA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found Isa Souza's directions a little hard to follow, so here's exactly what to do:

- Download
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SublimeText/LegacyColorSchemes/master/Mac%20Classic.tmTheme
- Save in new folder
  `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Mac Classic.tmTheme`
- Restart Sublime
- Preferences, Color Scheme, pick Mac Classic.